# SQL Set Cell Value Depending on Adjacent Cell Value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I added a new column in one of my database tables.  I'd like to try to populate that column for previous records.  New records will be validated through forms.  Here is an example.

```
| Quantity | Description         | Price | Amount | Type |
----------------------------------------------------------
|        3 | Storage for Pallets |  3.99 |  11.97 | NULL |
|        3 | Handling for Pallets|  3.99 |  11.97 | NULL |
|        3 | Misc expense        |  3.99 |  11.97 | NULL |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I'd like to replace those null values based off of keywords in the description. For example the updated table would look like the following.

```
| Quantity | Description         | Price | Amount | Type     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|        3 | Storage for Pallets |  3.99 |  11.97 | Storage  |
|        3 | Handling for Pallets|  3.99 |  11.97 | Handling |
|        3 | Misc expense        |  3.99 |  11.97 | Misc     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any ideas on an update statement that will accomplish this?

Comment: I don't mind running additional statements for each keyword I choose. Want to keep it simple

Comment: Is there a primary key on the table? Are those all of the columns or just some?

Comment: It's a rails application and ActiveRecord does not set a primary key on the table....out of the box :) Those are all of the columns

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no primary key you have put the values into the where clause for all columns' values. Or at least enough so that there is no chance of the update hitting 2+ rows, based on your knowledge of the data.

Here is the first update as an example:

```
update tbl
   set "Type" = 'Storage'
 where "Quantity" = 3
   and "Description" = 'Storage for Pallets'
   and "Price" = 3.99
   and "Amount" = 11.97;
```

**Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9fa64/1/0

If there were a primary key, your WHERE clause would be a lot simpler:

```
 where pk_id_field = x
```

(Because you could rest assured knowing you're about to update the exact row needed, and that no other rows have that value)

Answer (score 0):

It was simpler than I thought

```
UPDATE
  invoice_line_items
SET
  line_item_type = "Storage"
WHERE
  description like "%storage%";
```

.....and so on

Comment: If that's how you want the update to work (by the description containing a certain word) across the whole table, then that would be fine

Answer (score 0):

Actually: If you always want the description's first word for the type, you can go with

```
UPDATE Invoice_Line_Items
SET line_item_type = SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, ' ', 1);
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7d3d/2). You could, of course, add a `WHERE` clause, if it is not just as straightforward for the whole table… And you are not limited to the first word either…

Comment: That would be nice, but unfortunately you're expecting my users to be consistent lol.

Comment: I'd thought/hoped, the descriptions to be under your control. Bad luck.